# Problema con Recursividad en Python

Tags: python

tengo este código para buscar el mínimo de una lista con recursividad y sin utilizar la función min. pero quiero adaptarlo a buscar el mínimo de una matriz con recursividad.

consigna: desarrollar una función que devuelva el mínimo elemento de una matriz  NxM con recusividad.

```py
def minimo_lista(l):
    if len(l)>0:
         return l
    if len(l)==1:
        return l[0]    
    elif l[0] <= minimo_lista(l[1:]):
            return l[0]
    else:
        return minimo_lista(l[1:])

l = [10,5,4,2,-20,303,-20]
print(minimo_lista(l))
```

Comment: Por favor pon el código como texto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Planteando la solución

Si tu código obtiene el mínimo de una lista y una matriz, en este, esta formada por listas, entonces lo único que necesitas es recorrer sobre esas sublistas y un simple `if` para diferenciar una lista de un número.

```py
def minimo_lista(l):
    if len(l)<=0: return l

    if type(l[0]) is int: #en caso l en la primera poscición sea un número
        if len(l)==1: return l[0]    
        elif l[0] <= minimo_lista(l[1:]):
            return l[0]
        else:
            return minimo_lista(l[1:])
    else: #para este caso sería si es una lista
        #iteramos sobre las sub listas creando una lista con los resultados y aplicamos nuavamente la función
        return minimo_lista([minimo_lista(i) for i in l])


l = [[10,5,4,2,-20,303,-20],[10,20,-10],[-3,90],[-40,41]]
print(minimo_lista(l))
```

Creo que en lo único que te puedes confundir es en el bloque `else` del segundo `if`. Para ese caso usamos una comprensión de lista (*list comprehension*) cuya sintaxis es:

```py
resultado = [<operacion> for <variable> in <iterable>]

# que es igual que hacer:
resultado = []
for <variable> in <iteerable>:
    resultado.append(<operacion>)
```

### Explicación

En este caso si `l[0]` **no es un número** se pasa al bloque `else` donde iteramos en cada sublista de la matriz y para cada una de esas listas aplicamos la función de forma recursiva y es ahí donde si se cumplirá el segundo `if` haciendo el proceso de forma normal como lo haría con una lista y devolviendo un resultado, ese resultado es almacenado y lo mismo para las otras sublista, esto devuelve una lista de todos los números menores de cada sublista y entonces solo nos faltaría encontrar el menor de esa lista.

Si se te complica mucho entenderlo te dejo el código "normal":

```py
def minimo_lista(l):
    if len(l)<=0: return l
    if type(l[0]) is int: 
        if len(l)==1: return l[0]    
        elif l[0] <= minimo_lista(l[1:]):
            return l[0]
        else:
            return minimo_lista(l[1:])
    else:
        resultado = []
        for i in l:
            resultado.append(minimo_lista(i))
        return minimo_lista(resultado)


l = [[10,5,4,2,-20,303,-20],[10,20,-10],[-3,90],[-40,41]]
print(minimo_lista(l))
```

### Notas

Como últimos detalles,algo que dije anteriormente:

> En este caso si `l[0]` **no es un número** se pasa al bloque `else`

Esto quiere decir que si accidentalmente colocas un valor que no sea númerico, como por ejemplo un booleano o string tambien se pasará al bloque `else` y para este caso lo mejor sería colocar un `elif type(l[0]) is list:` y un `else: raise ValueError()`

Y el otro detalle es que las comprensiones de lista son mucho más rápidas que los ciclos `for` convencionales lo que viene ventajoso en la recursividad (que no es nada buena)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias me sirvió un montón tu explicación. pero si es que yo quisiera no usar un for al final, sino que recorrer las sublistas de la matriz con recursividad, ósea llamando a la función pero agregándole ademas de la sablista, una variable "filas" que vaya sumando +1 por vuelta como podría hacer?.

Comment: En la forma en que te muestro se usa la recursión, pero si mal no entiendo, para lo que quieres necesitarías un ciclo `while` y supongo que agregar un parámetro opcional en la declaración de la función

Comment: okay, gracias por tu consejos y ayuda. :)